# SAPUI5: View: How to introduce logic to the View-Panel, in order to change the representation of an Table

Tags: javascript, mysql, model-view-controller, datatable, sapui5

I want to change how a particular table is being shown.
Right now it looks as the following: [image]

How i want it to be:

```
Name   Value
1.    ar1,ar2,ar3
2.    ra1, ra2
```

I can achieve this goal within the controller but it messes up with certain logic, 
this is why changing how it is being shwon, is best to be done in the **View Page**.

Issue: How can i achieve this change with the help of **View-Page**

Comment: Aggregate the values in a second (JSON)Model, bind table to new model

Comment: If you are using the `sap.m` table, you can also try `mergeDuplicates="true"`  column property. [Table Merge Cells](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableMergeCells)